# Setup bind9 dns for setup DKIM and SPF records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, spf, dkim, opendkim

Currently emails from my mail server is blocked by gmail. I want to setup DKIM and SPF records for my mail server.But web domain register doesn't allow me to setup DKIM and SPF records it says I need to setup separate dns server for those records. Can I setup and configure bind9 dns server to setup DKIM and SPF records for my mail server?.Is it good to install both dns and mail server in same physical server. I am using Ubuntu 20LTS os

Comment: "Is it good to install both dns and mail server in same physical server. I am using Ubuntu 20LTS os" Obviously, if you are still at this level of questioning the design (with a far too vague and large question), I agree with Håkan answer that you should instead select a proper DNS provider. You seem also to conflate the role of a domain name registrar, which can also be a DNS provider but not necessarily, it can be an external party, and can be also a webhosting company, but not necessarily. No sane DNS provider would miss having the feature to edit `TXT` records.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek is there any free dns providers which I can get the service?

Answer (score 1):

First off, both the [DKIM spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376) and the [SPF spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7208) only use `TXT` records, which are very likely to be supported.

But if, for whatever reason, you really do need a different authoritative DNS service I would suggest that you first consider using some existing service provider rather than immediately jumping to adding things to your own infrastructure (particularly things that you are not familiar with).
That is, unless this is specifically an educational endeavor.

It would be possible to run an authoritative DNS server side by side with your mail server software if that is desired, though. But you ought to have at least two nameservers, whether your own infrastructure or not.